# How to use input$id value as an argument in function

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm trying to allow user to select two input one for group by and another for sum in a shiny app. those input will be used to further create a summary table.

Below is the code

```
    library(shiny)
    library(dplyr)
    library(DT)


    df <- iris
    vchoices <- colnames(iris)
    ui <- fluidPage(h1("PLOT FOR NOW"),
                    sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(
                      fluidPage(
                        column(10,selectInput(inputId = "group",label = "Group BY",choices = vchoices)),
                        column(10,selectInput(inputId = "sum",label = "SUM",choices = vchoices,selected = "Sepal.Length"))
                      )

                    ),
                    mainPanel(tabsetPanel(tabPanel("table",dataTableOutput("table"))
                    )))
    )

    server <- function(input,output,session){
      df1 <- reactive({df %>% group_by_(input$group) %>% summarise( fb =sum(input$sum))})

      output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df1())



    }

    shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Now i have been able to use **input$group** with help of **group_by_** function but how do I use it for sum in summaries ?

Comment: Use `get(input$sum)` to get the value in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you should use `get()` to get the value in the input.

You can also use it along `group_by(get(input$group))` instead of `group_by_(input$group)`

Here is the modified server function which should work :

```
   server <- function(input,output,session){
   df1 <- reactive({
   df %>% group_by_(input$group) %>% summarise( fb =sum(get(input$sum)))})

   output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(df1())

  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!
I have one doubt about how else get can be used 
Can I use it to convert a character say "mean" from `input$operator` to function `mean` in `get(input$operator)(get(input$sum))`  ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. You can use `get(input$operator)` to get the function `mean` if you have `"mean"` as your input.